# how to hide and show button using dropdown options?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I just want to hide a button defaultly and when i select any dropdown list the button comes

**[FIDDLE HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/joelshah/y3dgxc6w/2/)**

```js
$(function() {
  $('#cashbill').change(function() {
    $('#bill_icon').hide();
    $('#bill_icon' + $(this).val()).show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group col-4" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">
  <label class="col-sm-12 control-label p-sm-0">Bill type :</label>
  <select class="form-control selectsch_items" name="cashbill" id="cashbill" required>
    <option value="">Choose an items</option>
    <option value="1">Raw</option>
    <option value="2">Spare</option>
    <option value="3">Others</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group cash-billbtn">
  <label class="col-sm-12 control-label p-sm-0"></label>
  <button type="button" class="bill-btn" id="bill_icon">Bill</button>
</div>
```

to shown.. i just tried jQuery but its not work for me..

Comment: Do you want hide button Bill first and show this button when select a item in select tag? Also this code "$('#bill_icon' + $(this).val()).show();" : when user select item with value "1 or 2 or 3" so id name is bill_icon1, bill_icon2, bill_icon3. those name not exists in your html.

Comment: You can use `toggleClass`, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58040904/3367974). controlling display using `css` in much better and more flexible.

Comment: One small doubt.. "see here is 3 dropdown value is there, 1.Raw, 2. spare and 3.others.. now i want to click raw or spare value then the button wantsto come.. otherwise the button will be hidden always.. how?" example if i select **others** i dont want to show button..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just hide the button at first , then check if no value select to hide or show ( using value length as below )

```
$(this).val().length ?  $('#bill_icon').show() :  $('#bill_icon').hide();
```

see below snippet

```js
$(function() {
 
  $('#bill_icon').hide();
  $('#cashbill').change(function() { 
     $(this).val().length ?  $('#bill_icon').show() :  $('#bill_icon').hide();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group col-4" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">
  <label class="col-sm-12 control-label p-sm-0">Bill type :</label>
  <select class="form-control selectsch_items" name="cashbill" id="cashbill" required>
    <option value="">Choose an items</option>
    <option value="1">Raw</option>
    <option value="2">Spare</option>
    <option value="3">Others</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group cash-billbtn">
  <label class="col-sm-12 control-label p-sm-0"></label>
  <button type="button" class="bill-btn" id="bill_icon">Bill</button>
</div>
```

if you want to check by text value not value use the beow snippet :

```js
$(function() {
 
  $('#bill_icon').hide();
  $('#cashbill').change(function() { 
    var text = $(this).children("option:selected").text();
   ( text == "Raw" || text == "Spare"  )?  $('#bill_icon').show() :  $('#bill_icon').hide();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group col-4" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">
  <label class="col-sm-12 control-label p-sm-0">Bill type :</label>
  <select class="form-control selectsch_items" name="cashbill" id="cashbill" required>
    <option value="">Choose an items</option>
    <option value="1">Raw</option>
    <option value="2">Spare</option>
    <option value="3">Others</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group cash-billbtn">
  <label class="col-sm-12 control-label p-sm-0"></label>
  <button type="button" class="bill-btn" id="bill_icon">Bill</button>
</div>
```

Comment: its working bro.. thank you.. and one small doubt for knoledge purpose.. "see here is 3 dropdown value is there, 1.Raw, 2. spare and 3.others.. now i want to click raw or spare value then the button wantsto come.. otherwise the button will be hidden always.. how?" example if i select **others** i dont want to show button..

Comment: Just check the value , wether its equal to raw or spare by getting its text value not option attr value using `$(this).children("option:selected").text()`
See second added snipet

Answer (score 1):

This could be done this way in jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $('#bill_icon').hide();

  $('#cashbill').change(function() {
    if (this.value) $('#bill_icon').show();
    else $('#bill_icon').hide();
  });
});
```

But this has some problems:
 - If your page delays to load, it will show the button, and then it will hide it (flashing items)
 - This depends on JS been enabled

What I suggest you, is to hide the button on css, and then control its visibility.

---

What I do when I want this kind of behavior:

```
<label>Bill type :</label>
<select name="cashbill" id="cashbill" required>
  <option value="">Choose an items</option>
  <option value="1">Raw</option>
  <option value="2">Spare</option>
  <option value="3">Others</option>
</select>
<button type="button">Bill</button>
```

Hide by default on CSS, and only show it when select has a valid option:

```
select:invalid + button {
  display: none;
}
select:valid + button {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

add css above like here.

```
  .bill-btn{
    display: none;
  }
```

change your jquery like this.

```
$(function() {
   $('#cashbill').change(function() {
   if($(this).val() != "others"){
    $('#bill_icon').hide();
    $('#bill_icon' + $(this).val()).show();
    $(".bill-btn").show(); // added this line here
  }
 });
});
```

Comment: thank you bro.. and one small doubt for knoledge purpose.. "see here is 3 dropdown value is there, 1.Raw, 2. spare and 3.others.. now i want to click raw or spare value then the button wantsto come.. otherwise the button will be hidden always.. how?" example if i select **others** i dont want to show button..

Comment: @Joe i have updated the answer as i understand please check and let me know is this you ask

Comment: if i select others options i dont want to show the button.. only show the button for select Raw and spare options..

Answer (score 1):

Another way is using jQuery's [toggleClass](https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/):

1. Add `hidden` class to the button, it will hide the button at first load.
2. Use `toggleClass` inside `change` event of `select` like this:

   ```
   $('#cashbill').change(function() {
       $('#bill_icon').toggleClass('hidden', $(this).val() === '');    
   });
   ```

Basically you prevent toggling class when selected item is not first item.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/mLesd3kn/) is working fiddle.